# Show dual space of $\Bbb{F}_n$ is $~_n\Bbb{F}$

Tags: field-theory, homological-algebra, dual-spaces

Fix a field $\Bbb{F}$, and consider the following exact sequence:
$$ 
0\to~_n\Bbb{F}\to\Bbb{F}\to\Bbb{F}_n\to0
$$
where $~_n\Bbb{F}$ is the kernel of $\Bbb{F}\stackrel{\times n}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb{F}$ and $\Bbb{F}_n$ is the cokernel of this map.

I want to show the dual space of $\Bbb{F}_n$, that is $(\Bbb{F}_n)^*$ is isomorphic to $~_n\Bbb{F}$.

Could anyone give me some hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is a little strange since multiplication by $n$ in a field is either the zero map or is invertible, so $\mathbb{F}_n$ and $\mbox{}_n\mathbb{F}$ are both $0$ or $\mathbb{F}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have the right exact sequence
$$F \xrightarrow{\cdot n} F \rightarrow F_n \rightarrow 0$$
and applying $\operatorname{Hom}(-,F)$ gives us the left exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(F_n,F) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(F,F) \xrightarrow{(\cdot n)^\ast} \operatorname{Hom}(F,F)$$
Under the natural isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(F,F)\cong F$ the last arrow becomes $\cdot n$, hence by exactness of the second sequence
$$\operatorname{Hom}(F_n,F)=\ker(\cdot n) = {}_nF.$$